# How can I make dynamically created divs flush with eachother?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a function that creates a grid of divs that are generated and sent to a container div when the document loads (or when the user resets it). Everything seems to be about the way that I like it, except that there is a gap between each "row" of divs. I'd like it to be a perfect grid, with each square flush with each other. I've tried modifying borders, outlines, padding and the like with no success. I'm convinced there has to be a way to make this work that is less complicated than I am making it out to be. jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/psyonix/1g9p59bx/84/

```
var d = ("<div class='square'></div>");

function createGrid(numSquares) {
    var area = $('#g_area');
    var n = 0;
    var squareSize = (area.innerWidth() / numSquares);
    for (var i = 0, len = (numSquares * numSquares); i < len; i++) {
        area.append(d);        
    }

    $('.square')
        .height(squareSize)
        .width(squareSize)
```

---

```
#g_area {
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
    position: relative;
    width: 580px;
    height: 600px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.square {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
    outline-color: #000000;
    outline-width: 1px;
    outline-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: **[Something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/1g9p59bx/89/)**?

Comment: Something EXACTLY like that! Thanks for working that out!

Comment: Yes please, that'd be great!

Comment: @PaulRandall off-topic: you have an issue when you select grid size of 12 or 20

Comment: You mean where the grid is cut off inside the containing div? I'm still working out how to make it so the divs can fill the container. So far this is the best I can do. Ideally I could use some sort of math to make it so the divs dynamically adjust to fill the container without anything being cut off. I'm still a novice though. :/

Comment: Yea that's what I meant. I would use something else in order to solve your issue. I would put on area_g class `font-size:0` and keep the outline

Comment: by the way, if you will use in `.square` box-sizing:border-box` your calculations will probably be easier.

Comment: Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to either remove a `outline-width` from `.square` or give it some `2px` or `3px` value.

```
.square {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
    outline-color: #000000;
    outline-width: 3px; //or 2px or just remove it as I have done in my DEMO
    outline-style: solid;
}
```

**[DEMO HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/1g9p59bx/89/)**

Comment: It HAD to be something that simple. Thanks again!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy Coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You are using `inline-block` on the square elements, so the square elements will act [like the words inside a paragraph](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-boxes), and will be laid out as in lines of a sentence. These lines will have `line-height` just as in normal sentences, so one way is to reset the line-height of the parent holding these square *words*.

```
#g_area {
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
    position: relative;
    width: 580px;
    height: 600px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    line-height: 0px;
}
```

This way you can JAM the lines as you are not exactly looking for lines as in normal sentences.

---

Another way is to avoid using the `inline-block` and using `block` and `float` to attain the same. Block display doesn't have the issue of line-height or white-spaces between elements.

```
.square {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #C8C8C8;
    outline-color: #bc0000;
    outline-width: 1px;
    outline-style: solid;
    display:block;
    float:left;
}
```

---